# Trying to calculate a sum within a module - why is the iterator not creating integers?

Tags: scripting, scoping

Suppose I have the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm];

foo[bar_?IntegerQ, baz_?IntegerQ] = bar;

M[g_?IntegerQ] = Module[
    {sum},
    sum = Sum[foo[i, g], {i, 1, 4} ];
    N[sum]
];

Print[M[1]]
```

Why does this output:

```
foo[1., 1] + foo[2., 1] + foo[3., 1] + foo[4., 1]
```

When simply changing the `g` to a `1` as following correctly interprets the iterator as an integer?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm];

foo[bar_?IntegerQ, baz_?IntegerQ] = bar;

M[g_?IntegerQ] = Module[
    {sum},
    sum = Sum[foo[i, 1], {i, 1, 4} ];
    N[sum]
];

Print[M[1]]
```

This outputs (as expected):

```
10
```

Comment: I've added an answer below, but I'm still trying to figure out what exactly your function is for. The way it is written, all it does is sum the range from 1 to 4 no matter what argument is passed.

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry about what this is for. I created this smaller instance quickly from an instance in a larger script, which is why the `N[sum]` part is in it. I don't know how I overlooked the `SetDelayed` option; I've been looking at it for too long... Thanks!

Comment: 10-4. No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get your desired result by invoking the `SetDelayed` option for your functions. To output an Integer, remove the `N[]` function.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm];

foo[bar_?IntegerQ, baz_?IntegerQ] := bar;

M[g_?IntegerQ] := Sum[foo[i, g], {i, 1, 4}];

Print[M[1]]

(*10*)
```